# Is there any way to stay long term in Laos with an EU passport apart from going back and forth to Thailand all the time?

Tags: eu-citizens, laos

Is there any way to stay long term in Laos with an EU passport apart from going back and forth to Thailand all the time to get a new Laos 1 month tourist visa?

Comment: It will depend on your reason for wanting to do so eg  http://www.immigration.gov.la/visas.html If you’re basically just a visitor wanting to live there (ie not working, no family connection, no business interests etc) the answer is very probably no - in common with most other countries’ immigration policy.